# Error when trying to Segue a PFObject to the next View Controller (Swift 1.2)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, xcode6.3, pfobject

I am a newb to coding. 
I had no issues with creating a segue prior to the Swift 1.2 update. I am getting the error of `Cannot assign a value of type 'PFObject' to a value of type 'PFObject?'` when I try the code below. 
Can anyone help me figure this out ?

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "PushToDetails" {

    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    var detailScene = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController

    // Pass the selected object to the destination view controller.
    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
        let row = Int(indexPath.row)

        detailScene.currentObject = objects[row] as! PFObject
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your** error said can not assign a value of type `PFObject` to a value of type `PFObject!`. See the difference of between the `PFObject` and `PFObject!`?

- Because `PFObject!` is the type of `Optional`. Just like `String` and `String!`.They are the different types.
- Like what you written for `detailScene.currentObject = objects[row] as! PFObject`, the `currentObject` is the `Optional` type probably if you check it, which leads `detailScene.currentObject` to the `Optional` type.
- After that you assign the `objects[row]`, the `PFObject` type, to `detailScene.currentObject`, the `PFObject!` type.

**Maybe** you can correct your code like this,

```
    detailScene.currentObject! = objects[row] as! PFObject
```

Unwrapped the `currentObject` to the `PFObject` type.

Comment: Hi, I tried to use the official Syntax Convert Tool and it says there aren't any source changes necessary and I am still let with an error. Any thoughts?